# Visual Studio 2013 install gets blocked

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem installing VS2013 with update 4 included.

The install gets blocked everytime withe following error message:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3Fq2qIw.png]

log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ca019237eef8443573f

I would be glad is someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The log shows the installer being run as 'path: F:\VS2013.4.exe' .. Is this is the update to VS2013 or the actual VS2013 installer that includes u4? Are you also installing as admin? Have you clicked the link on the error window that says 'common issues and workarounds'?

Comment: @txtechhelp: You should post this as an answer; you are correct. VS2013.x.exe is the updater executable. The full installer executable should start with vs_, e.g., vs_professional.exe for the Professional Edition.

Comment: So is it possible that the 6GB ISO I got from Dreamspark is just the update?

Comment: The update isn't 6GB, so no, it's not just the update

Comment: Apparently it is, because I downloaded the Ultimate version without  Update from Dreamspark now (webinstaller), and now the 'update', which I tried to install as a standalone before, does apply.